# When syndicating an article to a third party site which is then the canonical, how should I update the json-ld Article schema URLs?

Tags: seo, canonical-url, json-ld, rel-canonical, open-graph-protocol

If I have a duplicate content because my article is syndicated to a third party site. which URLs should I use in json-ld Article schema? To be precise, let's say I want to publish an article from my `blog.example.xyz` on another site e.g. `popular.example.com`. When I publish the article on `popular.example.com` I go and update canonical URL on my `blog.example.xyz`, and `og:url` property (both should be same as implied [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514311/difference-between-rel-canonical-and-ogurl)):

```html
<!-- this is on blog.example.xyz -->
<link rel="canonical" href="https://popular.example.com/my-duplicate-article/">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://popular.example.com/my-duplicate-article/" />
```

I also use `http://schema.org/Article` to describe the Article entity, however, usually all URLs within it point to my own `blog.example.xyz`

```html
<!-- this is on blog.example.xyz -->
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Article",
    "author": {
      "name" : "Gitnik"
    },
    "headline": "My Duplicate Article",
    "description" : "Uhm, how do I deal with Article entity in case of duplicate content?",
    "inLanguage" : "en",
    "wordCount":  600 ,
    "datePublished" : "2020-05-18T21:00:00",
    "dateModified" : "2020-05-18T21:00:00",
    "image" : "http:\/\/blog.example.xyz\/img\/logo.png",
    "mainEntityOfPage" : "http:\/\/blog.example.xyz\/2020\/05\/my-duplicate-article\/",
    "publisher" : {
      "@type": "Organization",
      "name" : "http:\/\/blog.example.xyz\/",
      "logo" : {
          "@type" : "ImageObject",
          "url" : "http:\/\/blog.example.xyz\/img\/logo.png",
          "height" :  60 ,
          "width" :  60
      }
    }
  }
  </script>
```

but Google states that `mainEntityOfPage` [should be same as canonical URL](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/article). Now, it's easy to update `mainEntityOfPage` to the new url. But what about image URL and organization URL? Can image URL still my domain, or does it need to change to the domain of the canonical URL? And should I change Organization entity to the `popular.example.com` and change the URL there also? How would it affect SEO if I left them unchanged? How would it affect SEO if I left `mainEntityOfPage` unchanged?

Comment: Shouldn't your domain be the canonical?  If you have the original shouldn't the popular site point the canonical at your site?     By changing the canonical to their site you are giving them all the SEO value from this article.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller On some sites I cannot change canonical url, but I don't want to be penalized for duplicate content. So it's better to point my canoniacal url to third-party site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Which URL to use regarding canonicalization

Choose **one** canonical URL for your content, and use it **in every canonical attribute**, *i.e.* in:

- `<link rel="canonical" ...` (**it is the most important**),
- `<meta property="og:url" ...` and
- the structured-data property `Article.mainEntityOfPage`

**and in every page** that has the same content (the original page and the pages with the duplicate content).

### About JSON-LD `Article.image`

According to the [Google Developers Reference](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/article#article-types), you must specify an `Article.image` in your JSON-LD, **and** the URL specified in `Article.image` must be actually used (or *"marked-up"*) in the HTML code of the **current** article (with `<img src= ...`). This reference further states that this URL *"must be crawlable and indexable"*. In my understanding, it can be from a third-party domain.

### About JSON-LD `Article.publisher.name` and `Article.publisher.logo.url`

I would not pay too much attention on these as it should not significantly influence the ranking. I do not see any major SEO or technical issue if you use an image from the non-canonical domain. For the sake of consistency, I would stick to the image and URL of the **original publisher**.

### *“ How would it affect SEO if I left `mainEntityOfPage` unchanged? ”*

It do not think that it would be a big problem, as the main attribute for managing duplicate content in SEO is `<link rel="canonical" ...`.

Comment: Thank you! Though it's a bit confusing regarding the image url. In the documentation page I provided, by Google, it states that `mainEntityOfPage` is canonical url, and that image is `Only a marked-up image that directly belongs to the article should be specified` which implies that is should belong to the same domain.

Comment: @Gitnik, Sorry, I missed your question subpart about `Article.image`. I understand your citation from *Google Developers Reference* like this: you must specify, in your JSON-LD, an image that is actually used (or "*marked-up*") in the HTML code of the **current** article (with `<img src= ...`). This reference further states that `Article.image` must be "*crawlable and indexable*"; in my understanding, it might be hosted on a third-party domain. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Aha, so in case I don't actually have an image on my article (when posted on third-party site) `Article.image` I can leave out Article.image from Article? Also, since the Article is now on third-party site, should that be reflected too in `Article.publisher`?

Comment: @Gitnik, No, an `Article.image` is required in the JSON-LD of the current page, **and** `Article.image.url` must be used in this current page with `<img src= ...`.  Regarding `Article.publisher`, the short answer is no (please read my answer about that point).

Comment: Cool. Thanks. So the bottom line is to change canonical urls wherever I need to, but I can just leave other urls (image and publisher) as is. Thanks :)

Comment: @Gitnik, Yes, with the condition that, in a given page, `Article.image.url` must be used in an `<img src=...` HTML tag :)

Comment: Can you just clarify the difference between `Article.image` and `Article.image.url` in JSON-LD?

Comment: @Gitnik, My bad. You chose to specify the URL directly in `Article.image` (which is OK), and not to develop this `image` property into `Article.image.url`, `Article.image.width`, `Article.image.height`, *etc.* So when I write `Article.image.url`, you should read "the URL that is specified in `Article.image`". I will edit my answer to stick to your case.